# Basic Angularjs Autocomplete is not working within the project

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Its a very basic question,still i am facing a problem with angularjs auto complete.

html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div ng-controller="mainCtrl"c ng-app="myApp" class="row-fluid">
        <form class="row-fluid">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                Country Name <input type="text" class="form-control autocomplete" ng-model="selected" typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Controller/FlightBookController.js"></script>
```

My Controller Code:

```
angular.module('myApp', [['ui.bootstrap']])
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
alert("ddf");
app.controller("mainCtrl", function ($scope) {
    alert("ddf");
        //  $scope.selected = {id:'0',address:'Type 3 Letters'};
    $scope.selected = undefined;
    alert("kkk");
        $scope.states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois'];
    });
```

Even though the controller is recogonised by thr html(frontend) the auto complete function doesnt work.Where am i making the mistake.Is there any efficient way to do it.

Comment: ui.boostrap directive for typeahead is called `uib-typeahead` not `typeahead`. [See documentation](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#typeahead)

Comment: Try setting the `autocomplete` attribute to "true" on the form input element. I think that should work.